# Is there a wallet like Multibit for Litecoin?

Tags: client, litecoin, thin-clients

Is there a lightweight client like Multibit available for Litecoin? If not, is one in development?

Answer (score 2):

For a desktop computer, no, there's no lightweight client yet. There is [talk of developing](https://litecointalk.org/index.php?topic=8124.0) one, but it's not released yet. The LTC blockchain isn't as large as BTC's, so it's not as necessary on PCs.

For Android, there's a [Litecoin Wallet](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.schildbach.wallet_ltc) that is a lightweight client.

Answer (score 2):

There is a wallet called [Electrum LTC](https://electrum-ltc.org/).

There are versions for Windows, Linux and OS X.